# ImageView hiccup when setting large image

Tags: android

I have a `ListView` that contains large images--let's say it's filled with screenshots of the phone. When I scroll through the `ListView` there is a hiccup every time a new `View` becomes visible--as far as I can tell, due to setting the image.

I thought this may be due to `Bitmap` marshaling so I tried to create a `Bitmap` from a resource in an `AsyncTask` and then set it as the `ImageView`'s source bitmap on the UI thread, there is still a noticeable hiccup and dropped frames in the scrolling of my `ListView`.

It seems that this is not an issue when using smaller images, even if they are made to fit the whole `ImageView`. Unfortunately, the images I am trying to display are essentially screenshots, and thus almost as large as the size of the phone screen.

Before I set off on an exploration of the guts of `ImageView`, is there anything that can be done to avoid this? Clearly something is being done on the UI thread that is dependent on the size of the image, but can it be avoided/shuffled off to another thread, or otherwise optimized?

Comment: You can use image loading libraries such Picasso to load images, they are UI optimized and won't crash because of large image sizes.

Comment: My problem is not crashing, nor is it downloading images. All that is working fine. This is all to do with Android's ImageView. The images are also not loaded from a server. For the purposes of this question, imagine they are all resources in the app.

Comment: So then what is your issues? If no issues then why this ques?

Comment: Are you setting the full-size bitmap to a smaller imageview? If so, it may be more beneficial to shrink the bitmap to the correct size before assigning it to ImageView so the ImageView doesn't have to perform any scaling.

Comment: @DeeV the bitmap is sized to the size of the ImageView ahead of time, so that isn't a concern.

Comment: @AlokNair as I have stated in my question, the issue is the dropped frames in the scrolling of my ListView.

Comment: @Catherine are you storing the image caches and loading views from there is cache available or always loading new image?

Comment: @AlokNair when you say "loading," do you mean over the network? None of these images are requested over the network.

Comment: @DeeV actually I think you may be right. I just tried it out with images of differing sizes, and it looks like an image that's larger than the ImageView will cause hiccups on scrolling, presumably due to the work that must be done to resize it. There is probably a bug in my image sizing code. Thank you!

Comment: Hmm actually with large enough images, even if they're smaller than the ImageView, there is still a discernible slowdown. So that's not quite it.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `ImageView` source in `post()` method using `Handler` class in your custom list view adapter class.

e.g.

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.demoImage);
    }
});
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: This does not resolve the issue. The issue is that when I set the image resource there is a UI slowdown. It's not that I can't set it on the UI thread. I have no problem setting it on the UI thread.

Comment: Using handler post method, it will help in smoother transition of listview as every image will be loaded on separate thread. I have same problem loading images in listview and I ended up working out this way. Moreover you can also use https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader library for image loading, it works great.

Comment: The handler post method performs its actions on whatever thread the Handler was created on.

Comment: Yeah that's true but the runnables created in post method are queued up and run after the thread is done with its current work on. I have implemented my listview this way and is working fine.  I am sorry that this solution doesn't worked for you!